# Why is adding a constructor to call an external contract causing a cascading effect on the children requiring them to be marked abstract?

Tags: constructor, abstract

I'm having issues with compiling this contract, this contract sits in a series of inherited contracts. Its #6 of 8 contracts that make up the whole NFT contract. Before adding the constructor I was able to compile them all, but the last contract was slightly too large to deploy so I broke the largest contract out into an external contract so that I could call it and save some size.

I've double, triple checked that the functions from the external contract are implemented. It seems to be an issue with the constructor itself.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "./StringUtils.sol";
import "./AlumDAOTestDonation.Sol";
import "./AlumDAOTestActivityExternal.sol";



contract AlumDAOTestActivity is AlumDAOTestDonation {
    using StringUtils for bytes32;
    using SafeMath for uint256;

    AlumDAOTestActivityExternal public activityExternal;

  constructor(address _alumDAOTestActivityExternalAddress) AlumDAOTestDonation() {
    activityExternal = AlumDAOTestActivityExternal(payable(_alumDAOTestActivityExternalAddress));

}

    function setDecayConstant(uint256 _decayConstant) public onlyAdmin {
        activityExternal.setDecayConstant(_decayConstant);
    }

    // Call the logWork function using the activityExternal instance
    function logWork(uint256 tokenId, bytes32 description) public {
        activityExternal.logWork(tokenId, description);
    }

    // Call the confirmWork function using the activityExternal instance
    function confirmWork(uint256 tokenId, uint256 witnessTokenId) public {
        activityExternal.confirmWork(tokenId, witnessTokenId);
    }

    // Call the updateWorkContributions function using the activityExternal instance
    function updateWorkContributions(address patron, uint256 amount) public onlyAdmin {
        activityExternal.updateWorkContributions(patron, amount);
    }

    // Call the getActivityScore function using the activityExternal instance
    function getActivityScore(address patron) public view returns (uint256) {
        return activityExternal.getActivityScore(patron);
    }

    // Call the getActivityCount function using the activityExternal instance
    function getActivityCount(address patron, uint256 tokenId) public view returns (uint256) {
        return activityExternal.getActivityCount(patron, tokenId);
    }

    // Call the recordActivity function using the activityExternal instance
    function recordActivity(uint256 tokenId, uint256 amount) public onlyAdmin {
        activityExternal.recordActivity(tokenId, amount);
    }
}
```

The interface on the contract that it's calling

```
interface IAlumDAOTestActivityExternal {
    function setDecayConstant(uint256 _decayConstant) external;
    function logWork(uint256 tokenId, bytes32 description) external;
    function confirmWork(uint256 tokenId, uint256 witnessTokenId) external;
    function updateWorkContributions(address patron, uint256 amount) external;
    function getActivityScore(address patron) external view returns (uint256);
    function getActivityCount(address patron, uint256 tokenId) external view returns (uint256);
    function recordActivity(uint256 tokenId, uint256 amount) external;
}
```

Comment: What's the error returned by the compiler? If you changed the constructor perhaps you need to update the derived clases to pass the new parameter added.

Comment: Check that inheritance hierarchy is correct and the child contracts do not have unimplemented methods from any other interface they inherit

Comment: So I got it to compile by removing the constructor from the contract causing the issues. I replaced it with this instead to assign the external contract to a variable:



AlumDAOTestActivityExternal public activityExternal;

    function initializeActivityExternal(address _alumDAOTestActivityExternalAddress) public onlyAdmin {
        require(address(activityExternal) == address(0), "ActivityExternal has already been initialized");
        activityExternal = AlumDAOTestActivityExternal(_alumDAOTestActivityExternalAddress);
    }